# Which settings are required for messages on Status OpenVPN on DD-WRT?

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt, wrt54g

On a Linksys Router WRT54G v3.1 is installed the DD-WRT firmware v3.0-r44715 vpn ([dd-wrt.v24_vpn_generic.bin](https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/betas/2020/11-03-2020-r44715/broadcom/)), for a vpn server. On ***Services -> VPN*** the settings and entries have been made. OpenVPN is running according PID 5477 `/tmp/openvpnserver --config /tmp/openvpn/openvpn.conf --daemon`:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# ps
  PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
    1 root       940 S    /sbin/init noinitrd
    2 root         0 SW   [keventd]
    3 root         0 RWN  [ksoftirqd_CPU0]
    4 root         0 SW   [kswapd]
    5 root         0 SW   [bdflush]
    6 root         0 SW   [kupdated]
   10 root         0 SW   [mtdblockd]
   17 root      1524 S    watchdog
 1970 root      1468 S    telnetd
 4134 root      1456 S    -sh
 5327 root      1452 S    syslogd -Z -L
 5347 root       504 S    cron
 5438 root      1392 S    pppd file /tmp/ppp/options.pppoe
 5440 root      1528 S    /tmp/ppp/redial 30
 5445 root      1528 S    ttraff
 5467 root       824 S    dnsmasq -u root -g root -C /tmp/dnsmasq.conf
 5471 root      1460 S    wland
 5477 root      2848 S    /tmp/openvpnserver --config /tmp/openvpn/openvpn.conf --daemon
 5479 root       516 S    igmprt /tmp/igmpproxy.conf
 5533 root      1960 S    httpd -n -p 80
 5539 root      1268 S    resetbutton
 5584 root      1532 S    process_monitor
 5603 root      1456 S    -sh
 5605 root      1456 R    ps
```

But on the output of DD-WRT ***Status -> OpenVPN*** are there no entries:
[image]

Syslogd on ***Services -> Services*** is enabled:[image]

The vpn connection is currently not possible. `telnet xxx.57.124.83 1194` don't work, in opposite to `telnet xxx.57.124.83 53`

Which other settings or which additional measures are required to get at least ***Status -> OpenVPN*** message(s)?

Answer (score 0):

No stable releases have been provided since 2010. All of the following releases are just beta builds. The provided firmware may or may not work or may have limitations. This is also the case with Broadcom release r44715. This release uses OpenVPN 2.5. I have tested several of following Broadcom builds (r46239, r49049, r50500). OpenVPN does not work with these. The check with `telnet` shows a running OpenVPN daemon:

```
telnet 192.168.1.1     replace 192.168.1.1 with your real router IP
DD-WRT login: root     only root, not admin or other
Password: <your password>
ps
```

Result:

```
...
8943 root      2848 S    /tmp/openvpnserver --config /tmp/openvpn/openvpn.conf --daemon
...
```

But OpenVPN does not listen to the set port 1194. This can be checked with the command `netstat -nutl`:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# netstat -nutl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:14            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34954         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*
```

There is missing a line according to a real working OpenVPN with:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*
```

OpenVPN for WRT Linksys routers (with Broadcom chip) only works before version 2.5. One such release is r36410. This can be downloaded from here:

https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/betas/2018/07-28-2018-r36410/broadcom
[dd-wrt.v24_vpn_generic.bin](https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/betas/2018/07-28-2018-r36410/broadcom/dd-wrt.v24_vpn_generic.bin)